# the Text Hopping python problem -- why does my code disfunction?

Tags: python

### I got the question:

> A special text code is invented to jump from one letter to another in
> some text.
>
> In this simplified form, text will only use letters A - F and each
> character has the following 'jump' meaning.
>
> A = jump back 3 characters
>
> B = jump back 2 characters
>
> C = jump back 1 character
>
> D = jump forward 1 character
>
> E = jump forward 2 characters
>
> F = jump forward 3 characters
>
> You always start on the first letter of the input text and follow the
> instructions.
>
> For example consider the input DEACFB
>
> We start on the first letter which is D

```
 DEACFB  
 ^  
 DEACFB   (after hop 1)  
  ^  
 DEACFB   (after hop 2)  
    ^  
 DEACFB   (after hop 3)  
   ^  
 DEACFB   (after hop 4)  
^
```

> By following the instructions, sooner or later you must either jump
> off of the word (either to the left or to the right) or you must get
> stuck in an infinite loop. Note that the latter letters FB were never
> reached.
>
> Input some text and output the number of hops required to jump off of
> the text or output infinite if it would never do so.
>
> Input Format:
>
> A single line of text
>
> Output Format:
>
> A positive whole number or the single lower-case word infinite
>
> Constraints:
>
> The word will be less than 100 characters long.

My code:

```
inp = input()
if len(inp) < 101:
  place = 0
  list_of_letters = []
  inf = False
  while not inf:
    if place >= len(inp) or place < 0:
      print(len(list_of_letters))
      inf = True #even though its not inf!
    elif place in list_of_letters:
      print('infinite')
      inf = True
    elif inp[place] == 'A':
      place -= 3
      list_of_letters.append(place)
    elif inp[place] == 'B':
      place -= 2
      list_of_letters.append(place)
    elif inp[place] == 'C':
      place -= 1
      list_of_letters.append(place)
    elif inp[place] == 'D':
      place += 1
      list_of_letters.append(place)
    elif inp[place] == 'E':
      place += 2
      list_of_letters.append(place)
    elif inp[place] == 'F':
      place += 3
      list_of_letters.append(place)
```

for some reason, the output is never what I desire:
It has to either print the correct number or 'infinite' when it's stuck in a loop.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending the future place instead of the current place to list_of_letters,
which is not correct, other than that it works ok.

Your code with a simple fix:

```html
inp = input()
if len(inp) < 101:
  place = 0
  list_of_letters = []
  inf = False
  while not inf:
    if place >= len(inp) or place < 0:
      print(len(list_of_letters))
      inf = True #even though its not inf!
    elif place in list_of_letters:
      print('infinite')
      inf = True
    elif inp[place] == 'A':
      list_of_letters.append(place)
      place -= 3
    elif inp[place] == 'B':
      list_of_letters.append(place)
      place -= 2
    elif inp[place] == 'C':
      list_of_letters.append(place)
      place -= 1
    elif inp[place] == 'D':
      list_of_letters.append(place)
      place += 1
    elif inp[place] == 'E':
      list_of_letters.append(place)
      place += 2
    elif inp[place] == 'F':
      list_of_letters.append(place)
      place += 3
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tomer Cohen explained the problem with your code.

I'd just like to present an alternative approach using a dictionary for the offsets. It's easy to add additional steps there.

```
OFFSETS = {
    'A': -3,
    'B': -2,
    'C': -1,
    'D': 1,
    'E': 2,
    'F': 3
}


def jump_letters(text):
    position = 0
    visited_positions = {0}
    while True:
        position += OFFSETS.get(text[position], 0)
        if position in visited_positions:
            return None
        if position < 0 or position >= len(text):
            return len(visited_positions)
        visited_positions.add(position)


def main():
    result = jump_letters('DEACFB')
    if result is None:
        print('infinite')
    else:
        print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's based on the same idea like your approach but takes flexibility a step further.